# Updating a form containing an image - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, multer

Im building an app with react-native, and the backend is in NodeJS connected to MongoDB.

Im using multer to upload and store the images.

I use the following post request for adding a product with an image, which works as expected:

```
router.post(`/`, uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req,res)=>{
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if(!category)
        return res.status(400).send("Invalid category.");
    
    const file = req.file;
    if(!file)
        return res.status(400).send("No image in the request.");
    
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;
    const fileName = req.file.filename;
    let product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`, 
        brand: req.body.brand,
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
    })
    product = await product.save();
    if(!product){
        return res.status(500).send('The product cannot be created.');
    }

    res.send(product);
})
```

The problem is when I am trying to PUT (update) a specific product, unless Im also updating the image, the PUT request fails with network error 404. Here is the PUT request:

```
router.put("/:id", uploadOptions.single("image"), async (req,res)=>{
if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)){
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid product ID.");
}
const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
if(!category)
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid category.");

const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
if(!product)
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid product!");

const file = req.file;
let imagePath;

if(file){
    const fileName = req.file.filename;
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;
    imagePath = `${basePath}${fileName}`;
}
else {
    imagePath = product.image;
}

const updatedProduct = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
    image: imagePath,
    brand: req.body.brand,
    price: req.body.price,
    category: req.body.category,
    countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
    rating: req.body.rating,
    numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
    isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
},
{
    new: true,
})
if(!updatedProduct){
    return res.status(500).send('The product cannot be updated!');
}
res.status(201).send(updatedProduct);
})
```

As you can see, I tried to check whether an image was sent, and if not, using the old image, but that doesn't work. I tried to add some console.logs inside the put request but it seems like it doesn't even go inside that request.
Im using axios to send the request

```
axios.put(`${baseURL}products/${item.id}/`, formData, config)
```

And afterward there is no response and an error is catched...

Hope I explained everything good enough, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're mounting `router` to the Express app? The 404 suggests the route doesn't exist and indeed by the looks of it, `${baseURL}products/${item.id}/` is different from `/:id`

Comment: Do you mean in app.js? `const ProductRouter = require('./routers/products'); ` and then `app.use(\`${api}/products\`, ProductRouter);`  what I think thats happening is that because there is no image update, it doesn't find the put request because of the second argument (uploadOptions.single('image') )

Comment: That would be weird . Matching a request to a route is based on request method and url. Express doesn't look at request type, body or what middleware is used on a route. Do you know where the 404 is coming from in your app? Could there be another middleware in the chain that responds with a 404 if the body/request type is unexpected? Like an authentication middleware.

Comment: The authentication is passed in the config argument, and it is working (because the same config is sent to the POST request and it works).  The "funny" thing is Im studying and developing this app via Udemy course, and the authors doesn't have any solutions aswell...

Comment: Yeah strange. If you have a link to a public github repo it would help so I can try and reproduce.

Comment: Could you share your multer config ? What is in `uploadOptions` ?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh `const uploadOptions = multer({storage: storage});`                    @Maxim Orlov atm I have the backend only, will upload the front soon. Here is the backend https://github.com/matanbe4/Shoply-server

Comment: @MatanBenishty I think your code fails at `const isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];` in the storage config. When the PUT request doesn't have a file, file is `undefined` so you'll get an error trying to access mimetype of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with the route, you should change

```
router.put(":/id"
```

to :

```
router.put("/:id"
```

Comment: Sorry it got messed up while I tried to figure out what to do. It wasn't the problem as Im having the same problem.  If Im not updating the image the put request fails.